# How do I specify that a mock has no interactions after a given timeout in mockito-scala?

Tags: scala, mockito, mockito-scala

I can't find a nice Scala DSL way to specify that a mock was not called at all after a specified duration.

Something like

```
aMock wasNever calledAgain after 2.seconds
```

The doc also doesn't mention anthing. 
https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala

UPDATE: See https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala/issues/253

Comment: You can use eventually from scala test and then validate it with patience config.

Comment: I could, but with mockito-scala I am nearly there, so how about the solution inside mockito-scala? Is it possible or not? That is the question.

Comment: Also in my current project I would have a hard time with a dependency on Scalatest only for this. I personally love it, but I am currently working in a project using an old Specs2 version. So I would have a hard time (for good reasons) arguing to add a dependency on Scalatest just for this.